# Transparent View in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using sliding drawer top to bottom.i have a imageview/view on that sliding drawer 100x100. and on main screen i have a image. i want to make that view on sliding drawer as transparent that i can see image which is on main screen. i am using this [code](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) for sliding drawer.
in simple words i have 2 view one on one and i want to see pic of first view from second view.

Comment: Are you sure the graphics you're using have alpha channels and that they are set to be transparent?

Answer (score 0):

**`android:background="#TTRRGGBB"`**

- `RR, GG, BB` are the RGB components of the color, respectively
- `TT` is the transparency component.

Use TT = 80 (hex) for 50% transparency, FF for no transparency, 00 for fully transparent.

Source : [Another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562962/transparent-widget-background).

Comment: Forgive me. I wasnt aware that it doesnt work for the widgets. Anyway, I have updated my answer. I am sure it would help you.

Comment: Plus, have a look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562962/transparent-widget-background

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the content part of your sliding drawer, transparent, you can do something like this;

```
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content"
        android:background="#eeffae" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/handle" android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp" android:src="@drawable/handle" />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@null">

...
...
</LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: i just want to make imageview which is 100x100 on my sliding drawer. and i have tried android:background="#eeffae" but its not working